# Why is the widget in this Listbox too small? GTK

Tags: c++, linux, gtk3, linux-mint

I'm building a small podcast application for Linux using GTK-3.0 I want to use a listbox To hold Search results however when I add a widget to the listbox its far too small [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdRqe.png)

I've put all of the ui stuff into a header file.

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
#include <iostream>
extern "C"{
void createSearchResults(GtkWidget *e);
void MakeWindow(int *x,char ***y)
{
  
  GtkWidget *listBox;
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  gtk_init(x,y);
  builder = gtk_builder_new();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "PodcastWindow.glade", NULL);
  listBox = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"SearchListBox"));
  window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"MainWindow"));
  gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder,NULL);
  g_object_unref(builder);
  gtk_widget_show(window);
  createSearchResults(listBox);
  gtk_main();
  return;
}
void on_MainWindow_destroy(){gtk_main_quit();}

void PodcastSearchEntry(GtkEntry *e){
  itunesSearch(gtk_entry_get_text(e));
}

void createSearchResults(GtkWidget *e){
  GtkWidget *tmp = gtk_label_new("helloWorld");
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(e),tmp);
}
}
```

I think the issue is somewhere in this function

```
void createSearchResults(GtkWidget *e){
      GtkWidget *tmp = gtk_label_new("helloWorld");
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(e),tmp);
    }
```

any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated.
PS if there are any formmating improvements I could make please let me know.

Comment: You will need to look at the Gtk+3 Documentation [gtk_box_set_child_packing()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-set-child-packing). (specifically the `expand` parameter)  The Gtk Builder interface is no replacement for actually writing a good interface. It has huge shortcomings in layout, etc.. `Builder == Initial Guess`. You may also want to look at the deprecated, but still useful `hbox` and `vbox` layout containers.

Comment: None of the remarks in the comment above really make any sense: A `GtkListBox` is not a `GtkBox`. For creating UIs, you can use `GtkBuilder` just fine, and that's what most GTK applications also do (note that there is a difference between GtkBuilder and Glade). You can also still use horizontal and vertical boxes: `GtkHBox` and `GtkVBox` have been deprecated because they can be replaced with just `GtkBox` and the appropriate "orientation" property set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to know what exactly is going wrong in your code without having a small example code that reproduces the issue.

That being said, one thing you should keep in mind, is that in GTK3, widgets are **not** visible by default (this got changed in GTK4 however). So what you probably want to do in your `createSearchResults()` function is to add `gtk_widget_show()` to the label you just made:

```
void createSearchResults(GtkWidget *e){
    GtkWidget *tmp = gtk_label_new("helloWorld");
    gtk_widget_show (tmp);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(e),tmp);
}
```

One possibility of analyzing where you have problems in your widget tree, is by taking a look with the [GTK inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Inspector). You can then click to inspect the widget that is not behaving as expected.

Comment: thanks the showing the widget fixed it. I also really appreciate the the information about GTK inspector as well, definitely going to use that.